# Powershell : Not all .dll load from the specified source LoadFrom

Tags: powershell, dll, azure-powershell

I am quite new to powershell and in one of the Powershell Project I am not able to load all the DLLs from the **same specified source $dllPath** using **LoadFrom**.

As shown, Az.NewUtility (first dll) references all below .dlls and all 9 dlls are present in my **DBScripts\KvProviderLib** Folder. 
But powershell automatically loads two from the folder **"Az.Accounts\1.2.1\"** instead from **DBScripts\KvProviderLib**

[image]

As per the functionality this project executes some Powershell commands like Get-AzContex, Get-AzKeyVault and once those commands are executed it tries to load the dlls using above code. But it loads these two dlls (Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll and Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.dll) from different source.

I need to load these two dlls (Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll and Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.dll) from the same folder I specified in $dllPath to execute the functions written in Az.NewUtility successfully.

Is there Anyway I can forcefully load them from the specified path i.e $dllPath and in the same Powershell session after commands Get-AzContex, Get-AzKeyVault  are executed?

**P.S** : If I open a new powershell session and execute the script it loads it from right source but it loads it from different source if I try loading it after executing Get-AzContext, Get-AzKeyVault Command.

Comment: They could be required for other DLLS to fully load. Have you tried Loading those 2 first then loading the others?

Comment: Yes, even if I tried to load them first they always get load from the path specified above. so even if I use first [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("..\KvProviderLib\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll") they get loaded from only the specified path from screenshot (..\1.2.1\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll)